# HTML and JavaScript - How to save plain text right

Tags: javascript, html, file-io

I want to save a locally generated textfile.

This code almost does what I want:

```
<a download="filename.txt" href="data:text/plain,sometext">Download</a>
```

`sometext` represents a `string` in that tag attribute (inserted using javascript).
You could imagine it as the content of a textarea which is set by the user.

The problem is that `sometext` must not contain `"` or `'` because otherwise the href attribute thinks that its content finishes earlier which causes the tag to just save a part of that `string` when you click on it.

As `sometext` is generated by the user, it can contain these characters and I do not want to force the user to not use these.

Is there another way to save text files using html/javascript?

I do not want to send `sometext` to the server. (Which would solve the problem because I could create a file there (including `"` and `'`) and feature a download link)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend on how are you adding this `something` to the href.

First of all, a single quote wont matter, because it is wrapped by double quotes `"`, so it will work well like this:

```
<a href="data:text/plain,mytext'text">Download</a>
```

When it comes to double quotes, in the HTML context you would have to use the correct notation, in this case it would be `&quot;`. The HTML will understand it as double quotes:

```
<a href="data:text/plain,mytext&quot;text">Download</a>
<!-- It will turn into mytext"text -->
```

**However**

Since you said that it will be an user's input, I suppose you might be setting the `href` through Javascript, so I don't think it would matter, it would be like this:

(Try typing single or double quotes... For JS it won't matter)

```js
var ChangeHref = function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("a1");
    el.href = "data:text/plain," + document.getElementById("inp1").value;
}
```

```html
<input id="inp1" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="change href" onclick="ChangeHref()" />

<br />

<a id="a1" download="filename.txt" href="data:text/plain,test">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a simple javascript to remove ' and " characters like so

```
userText.replace(/\'/g, '').replace(/\"/g, '');
```

The / means its a regex, the \' and \" represent the literal characters ' and " and the g at the end makes it find all to occurrences to replace.

But since you want to keep it then do this:

```
userText.replace(/\'/g, '\\\'').replace(/\"/g, '\\\"');
```

The \ is a literal backslash.  that way when you add it to the name of the file it will escape out and mean a literal ' and ".

Comment: I want to keep " and ' in the saved file